# Unity: Record real time game play in high quality using offline rendering?

Tags: unity, rendering, 360-video, game-recording, screen-recording

I'm looking to record Unity gameplay at really high quality (360 Stereo 8k 120 fps). I can't do this in real time due to the GPU resources required so I need to do offline rendering (frame perfect rendering).

The problem is offline rendering by its nature doesn't accept user input, so I can't record live gameplay footage. I'm looking for a solution that lets me record live gameplay and then render it out at this higher quality.

I considered recording the user input or the gameobjects properties and then playing them back while rendering the footage. I tried a number of assets like Ultimate Replay 2.0, Record and Play, GameObject Recorder, even tried Unity Recorder to an animation but none of them record all of the changes to components on a gameobject. I think I'll have to write my own code, although I'm not sure what the best method would be, I'm reluctant to sink to much development time into this if there's an easier solution that I've overlooked?

Initially I'm looking for a solution that works inside the Unity editor but would love to be able to give this ability to end users.

Comment: My approach would be to properly encapsulate all my input handling in a single behavior (if I hadn't done that already) and then add a recording ability to said class which is able to record player input with timecode to a file and later play back that file.

Comment: Are you trying to make a trailer or 3d movie? How about capturing gameplay footage at reduced speed (using `Time.timeScale`) and then later speed up that footage?

Comment: @Philipp It's a VR game so I'm guessing `Time.timeScale` wouldn't work due to the delay in the headset. I'm just attempting to get footage for trailer and general sharing.

Comment: Have you looked into [Unity's Filmmaking Solutions](https://unity.com/solutions/real-time-filmmaking-explained)? Alternatively, if your input is scripted & the game is deterministic, would it be possible to capture the video a section of the screen (i.e 1/4 the screen, to lower the GPU expense) at a time normally & then combine them in post?

Comment: @Pikalek unfortunately it is non-deterministic, but thanks for the advice of looking at the filmmaking solutions.